# Message boxes are not shown MessageBoxA()

Tags: windows, winapi, messagebox

There is something curious going on on my Windows machine.
I have an application that calls MessageBoxA(...)

```
auto errorCode = MessageBoxA(NULL, "Somtext", "Sometitle", MB_YESNO | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_DEFBUTTON1);
```

The problem is that the message box is never shown. The call to MessageBoxA(...) returns immediately and `errorCode` tells me that the default button was pressed. So far so strange. In addition to that here is what I also found out.

- The content of that message box which is not shown automatically appears as an entry in the Windows event log.
- This only happens for my application. I tried other applications and they show message boxes just fine.

I'm running Windows 7 embedded.
Is there someone out there which has an idea what's going on here?

Comment: here question in which "context" you call `MessageBoxA`. may be  after `WM_QUIT` message. if you insert `MessageBoxA` at very begin of this application - it will be shown?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9978975e-32d5-4f31-b874-fead3b318e3e/message-boxes-in-application-never-display?forum=quebeccomponentsforum

Comment: Remove all these flags that you put.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are those two registry keys:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Error Message Instrument\EnableDefaultReply
```

- 0 = "Disable" clicking the "default button"
- 1 = "Enable" clicking the "default button"

and

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Error Message Instrument\EnableLogging
```

- 0 = Do not log message boxes that have been handled by Dialog box filter (Application Log)
- 1 = Log message boxes that have been handled by Dialog box filter (Application Log)

A discussion about this can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9978975e-32d5-4f31-b874-fead3b318e3e/message-boxes-in-application-never-display?forum=quebeccomponentsforum)

Thank you Hans Passant